# Set builder notation vectors

Tags: notation

Suppose I want to describe  a set of vectors which can belong to two possible sets. That is, informally, all vectors $(x,y)\in (\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m)$ for which either $x = \mathbf{0}$ and $y\in   \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^m$ or $x\in   \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in  \mathbb{R}_{\geq k}^m$ (for some $k$). I am trying to write this down in proper set builder notation but so far to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about $(\{\mathbf{0}\}\times\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^m)\cup(\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R_{\geq k}^m)$?

Comment: @Zuy I though about this too but I was confused about the union symbol; does it not mean that $(x,y)$ can be any of the combinations of these two sets? So also $(\mathbf{0},  \mathbf{0})$ (when $k>0$).

Comment: A tuple $(x,y)$ in this union is either in the first part (meaning that $x$ is zero and $y$ consists of only positive entries) or in the second part (meaning that $x$ can be "anything" and the components of $y$ are at least equal to the fixed $k$). So yes, the tuple $(\mathbf 0,\mathbf 0)$ does belong to this union, but this is also accepted in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using connectives and quantifiers, such that the condition of your set abstraction is expressed in first-order logic? That is, write

$$\{ (x,y)\in (\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m) \mid (x = \mathbf{0} \wedge y\in   \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^m) \vee (\exists k. x\in   \mathbb{R}^n \wedge y\in  \mathbb{R}_{\geq k}^m)\}$$

Comment: I think putting $($ on the right side of $\exists k$ makes it more clear.